# Any elegant way of defining an alphanumerical subtype?

Tags: string, character, ada

This is my first ever question on this website. I always managed to find an answered question from some people with similar problem than mine, but this time there didn't seem to be any.

So here it is, I'm trying to generate a big amount of relatively short strings to use as ID numbers, but want them to only contain alphanumeric characters.

I've tried some things like:

```ada
subtype Char is character range 'a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0' .. '9';
```

adding parentheses, comma, create new type instead of subtype.

I know I could just enumerate all the characters I want but I just could resign myself to such a stupid task as writing every 62 character in a enumerated type.

Is there any way of concatenating different intervals into one subtype?

EDIT: so this is my code:

```ada
with ada.text_io, ada.integer_text_io, ada.float_text_io, ada.numerics.discrete_random;
use  ada.text_io, ada.integer_text_io, ada.float_text_io;

procedure randomID is

Subtype AlphaNumeric is character 
with dynamic_predicate => AlphaNumeric in 'a'..'z' |
                                          'A'..'Z' |
                                          '1'..'9' ;
package CharGen is new ada.numerics.discrete_random (Alphanumeric);
CharG: CharGen.generator;
id: string (1..5);

begin
    for i in 1..5 loop
        CharGen.Reset(CharG);
        id(i) := charGen.random(CharG);
    end loop;
end randomID;
```

But I am getting ( whether I use static or dynamic indicate ) these errors:

> 09: warning: in instantiation at a-nudira.adb:54
>   09: warning: type "Result_Subtype" has predicates, attribute "First" not allowed
>   09: warning: Program_Error will be raised at run time
>   09: warning: in instantiation at a-nudira.adb:54
>   09: warning: expression fails predicate check on "Result_Subtype"
>   09: warning: in instantiation at s-rannum.ads:86
>   09: warning: in instantiation at a-nudira.adb:53
>   09: warning: type "Result_Subtype" has predicates, attribute "Last" not allowed
>   09: warning: in instantiation at s-rannum.adb:395
>   09: warning: in instantiation at a-nudira.adb:53
>   09: warning: type "Result_Subtype" has predicates, attribute "Last" not allowed

I understand there is a conflict with the way Ada.numerics generates random items and the nature of my type. Is there a way to work this out ?

Comment: I have to say I'm puzzled by the close vote ... defining a type to meet a requirement is very much about programming. (However, I would recommend making an [MCVE] - a three-line main.adb that exercises this code especially since there's no way to relate the errors to any of the lines shown)

Comment: The errors are all in `ada.numerics.discrete_random` given your instantiation ... the compiler hasn't allowed you to instantiate with a (no longer compatible) subtype. I'll be honest I haven't the foggiest what the solution is, but I'd workaround with a wrapper that (e.g.) instantiates with the base type ("character") and rejects invalid values, returning only values that meet the predicate. Messy. So. not answering.

Comment: That's pretty messy. I think the only solution right now is to enumerate every character in a new type, as suggested ( even if I wanted to avoid it ).  Do you think I should mark this question as answered and post a new one for this problem, which doesn't really relate to the title of this question ?

Comment: See forthcoming answer...

Comment: I think I know where the problem comes from. My subtype is obtained from the scalar type Character, so they have the same Base value ( https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System#Base_type )   . The problem then comes from the fact that since they have the same base value, they probably have the same First' and Last' items, which the Discrete_random package use to generate random item. ( http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~beidler/Ada/gnat/a-nudira.html ) - And because these First and Last items are not in my subtype, there is no way the functions from the package could work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in at least two different ways.

As a subtype of `Character` using a static predicate:

```ada
subtype Alphanumeric_Character is Character
  with Static_Predicate => Alphanumeric_Character in 'a' .. 'z' |
                                                     'A' .. 'Z' |
                                                     '0' .. '9';
```

As a proper type:

```ada
type Alphanumeric_Character is ('a', 'A',
                                'b', 'B',
                                'c', 'C',
                                ...
                                'z', 'Z',
                                '0', '1', '2', '3', '4',
                                '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
```

Comment: "As a proper type"  enumerates all 62 possibilities, which OP wanted to avoid!

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know of the subtype predicate  function. It's going to be very useful in a lot of situations ( like this one ) so I don't understand why our teacher never told us about it. Have a nice day.

Comment: It's an Ada-2012 feature, when did your teacher last update the course?

Comment: She sure is an old-school teacher. Doesn't also really like us to learn by ourselves on the internet; whereas her course is pretty short: I had to dig by myself to learn about calendar and delay procedures, character handling, and all new ada2012 features, and she seems a bothered that I'm using all of these for our project.  Anyway, I tried something with my code but there's a problem between Ada.numerics.discrete_random and my subtype with static_indicate..

Comment: predicate, not indicate

Answer (score 1):

I finally decided it was time to play with predicates, having learned the little Ada I know long before 2012.

As subtypes with predicates are overlaid on the underlying type, there must have been some interesting discussions what to keep from the underlying type, what to prohibit and what to add...

Turns out that some predicates such as `'first, 'last, 'range` are prohibited, and you ran into these via their use in `a-nudira.adb` aka `ada.numerics.discrete_random`. There are replacements in the form of `'first_valid, 'last_valid` which DO work as expected, but not `'range` which would allow holes in the datatype.

And some others like `'pos, 'val, 'pred,'succ` survive BUT they refer to the underlying type, so `AlphaNumeric'Pred('A')` is '@' rather than '9' for example. This is inconvenient, but...

The essence of predicates is not to provide some magical programming that deals with holes in array addressing, etc, but to allow programming by contract.

And the essence of programming by contract is that both parties (caller and callee, instantiator and generic package) have to abide by the contract.

Unfortunately, `ada.numerics.discrete_random` doesn't abide by the contract. It may be possible to write a replacement that does, but that would be a bigger project than we need just now. (OTOH, If you're using Gnat Pro, such an enhancement MAY be covered under your support contract :-)

So here's a modification, using a wrapper function `random` that does abide by the contract...

```
with ada.text_io, ada.integer_text_io, ada.float_text_io, 
ada.numerics.discrete_random;
use  ada.text_io, ada.integer_text_io, ada.float_text_io;

procedure randomID is

pragma Assertion_Policy(Check);

Subtype AlphaNumeric is character 
with dynamic_predicate => AlphaNumeric in 'a'..'z' |
                                          'A'..'Z' |
                                          '1'..'9' ;

package CharGen is new ada.numerics.discrete_random (character);
CharG: CharGen.generator;

id : string (1..5);

    function random return AlphaNumeric is
    ch : character;
    begin
        loop
           ch := charGen.random(CharG);
           exit when ch in AlphaNumeric;
        end loop;
        return ch;
    end random;

begin
    for i in 1..5 loop
        CharGen.Reset(CharG); -- wait what? should be outside the loop
        id(i) := random;
    end loop;
    put_line(id);
end randomID;
```

Whether this is better than defining your own enumeration I can't say. However, arrays of that enumeration will be incompatible with strings, so you'll have some other form of wrapper to write if you go that road. I ran into this simply making `id` an `array (1 .. 5) of AlphaNumeric` which would ensure the caller enforces the contract too.

Comment: Glad I understood the source of the problem just before you explained it.   " exit when ch in AlphaNumeric " Looks even worse to me than enumerating every character aha. But that is for sure the shortest solution on the code ( not for the program ) . What is the "pragma Assertion_policy (Check)" for ?

Comment: For caution. It ensures predicates are checked - e.g. assignments to an AlphaNumeric will fail (Constraint Error exception) for other characters. Some compilers may leave some checks off by default.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I decided to go with this.
This is ugly, but it's anyway going to be hidden so I don't really care;
Brian Dumond's option is good, but I didn't really like the fact that it had to generate random character until they fortunately were alphanumerical.

```ada
procedure randomID is

Type Table is array (1..62) of character;
AlphaNumeric : Table := ('a','b','c'...'7','8','9');
Type Int is new integer range 1..62;
package intGen is new ada.numerics.discrete_random (Int);
intG: IntGen.generator;
id: string (1..5);

begin
    for i in 1..5 loop
        intGen.Reset(intG);
        id(i) := Alphanumeric(integer(intGen.Random(intG)));
    end loop;
end randomID;
```

Comment: You can just say `Alphanumeric : constant String := "abcdef ... 6789";` then declare a subtype `Integer range Alphanumeric'range;` and instantiate Discrete_Random with that subtype.